# How can I set a password for Visio files?

Tags: passwords, visio

I want to put a password on the files so no one can open without their permission

Comment: Interesting question, I'll test something. Give me a few moments :)

Comment: hey Mehdi, I added an update. Application.Quit on the document open event failed. I think this should work... as soon as a user enables the macros for this, this document will never open without a password

Comment: There were a few crucial changes needed... this should work.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the short answer is not unless you have password protection for zip files.

You can however test some vba code and play with visibility. It won't guarantee security of your document because Visio doesn't have flexibility to save as a Macro-Enabled drawing... limiting your ability to really secure it with VBA.

You could however pique the confusion of the undesired user reading/viewing by having all of your pages hidden... Security by obscurity if you will.... Unless they enable macros, they can still ideally do anything they want with the document which Is why you should use encrypted zip software and password protect the document that way.

Anyway... if you're still game for this crazy experiment I tried...

Enabled developer view. Then go into View Code.  So here's how this works... First you need to generate your password hash. Then once your password hash is created... Delete the entire

1. Copy all the main sub, the temporary sub, and the core subs and functions below to your "ThisDocument" object in the developer > View Code page
2. Set your password by entering your password in place of "Mypassword" in the GenMyPwd sub. You can execute it by leaving your curser in the text of that sub and clicking the "run" button at the top of the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications menu.
3. Once you see the pop-up, press Ctrl+V and paste the content to notepad. You'll get something to this effect.

   ```
   ---------------------------
   Your Password Hash
   ---------------------------
   78F56C460A6CA4B15554E5FE5469AA036FB21EFA7151E991D6F9A9FDA4548F79
   ---------------------------
   OK   
   ---------------------------
   ```
4. Once you have your hash, set the variable in the private for your own unique hash value.

   ```
   mypassword = "78F56C460A6CA4B15554E5FE5469AA036FB21EFA7151E991D6F9A9FDA4548F79"
   ```
5. One caveat though, you'll have to create a button for your HidePages Script... or create a key-capture event for a hotkey combination and use it add some additional vba code to Save, HidePages, and then close visio.

### Main Sub to capture open document event. - Will look like this before you set your variable

```
Private Sub Document_DocumentOpened(ByVal doc As IVDocument)
    Unauthenticated = True
    myPassword = ""
    Do While Unauthenticated
        'Add number of tries
        tries = tries + 1
        'Prompt Password
        TryPassword = InputBox("Enter the password", "Password Required!")
        'Hash Password attempt and compare to Current Hash
        If Sha256Hash(TryPassword) = myPassword Then
            'Escape the loop
            Unauthenticated = False
            Call ShowPages
        Else
            If ((tries > 2) And (Unauthenticated = True)) Then KillVisio
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

### Main Sub After you set your variable

```
Private Sub Document_DocumentOpened(ByVal doc As IVDocument)
    Unauthenticated = True
    myPassword = "6DA6F219DAC977DA75F2F2894F33ABAD5052AF2A60AE9219AF0E302EDDD5BBC4"
    Do While Unauthenticated
        'Add number of tries
        tries = tries + 1
        'Prompt Password
        TryPassword = InputBox("Enter the password", "Password Required!")
        'Hash Password attempt and compare to Current Hash
        If Sha256Hash(TryPassword) = myPassword Then
            'Escape the loop
            Unauthenticated = False
            Call ShowPages
        Else
            If ((tries > 2) And (Unauthenticated = True)) Then KillVisio
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

### Additional Required Subs and functions

```
Sub KillVisio()
    Set WShshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strcommand = "C:\windows\system32\taskkill /im visio.exe -f"
    WShshell.Run ("cmd /c " & strcommand)
End Sub
Sub GenMyPwd()
    MsgBox Sha256Hash("P@ssw0rd"), vbExclamation, "Your Password Hash"
End Sub
Sub ShowPages()
    Set vPages = ThisDocument.Pages
    For i = 1 To vPages.Count
        Set Visibility = vPages(i).PageSheet.CellsU("UIVisibility")
        If Visibility = 1 Then
            Visibility.FormulaU = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Sub HidePages()
Set vPages = ThisDocument.Pages
    For i = 1 To vPages.Count
        Set Visibility = vPages(i).PageSheet.CellsU("UIVisibility")
        If Visibility = 0 Then
            Visibility.FormulaU = 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Function Sha256Hash(str)
    Dim b() As Byte
    b = str
    Sha256Hash = BytesToHex(Sha256HashBytes(b))
End Function
Function MD5HashBytes(aBytes)
    Set objsha256 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider")
    s = objsha256.Initialize()
    MD5HashBytes = objsha256.ComputeHash_2((aBytes))
End Function
Function Sha256HashBytes(aBytes)
    'Set objsha256 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider")
    Set objsha256 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed")
    With objsha256
        s = .Initialize()
        Sha256HashBytes = .ComputeHash_2((aBytes))
    End With
End Function
Function StringtoUTFBytes(aString)
    Set UTF8 = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    StringtoUTFBytes = UTF8.GetBytes_4(aString)
End Function
Function BytesToHex(aBytes)
    For x = 1 To LenB(aBytes)
        hexStr = Hex(AscB(MidB((aBytes), x, 1)))
        If Len(hexStr) = 1 Then hexStr = "0" & hexStr
        BytesToHex = BytesToHex & hexStr
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Please mind that VBA password protection is not secure at all. There are a lot of (sort of "hacking") programs that allow you to remove any VBA-based password protection in one click. Not to speak about events-based ("DocumentOpened") protection. You can just disable the macros, and the protection is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Visio 2016 includes Rights Management support. This feature basically allows you to protect the document and specify who can do what with that document.

Maybe that is what you are after?